# Lindemann–Hinshelwood mechanism for a gas reaction

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics, rate-equation

> The effective rate constant for a gaseous reaction which proceeds by a Lindemann–Hinshelwood mechanism is  $\pu{1.01E-5 s^-1}$ at a concentration of $\pu{4.6E-6 M}$ and $\pu{2.21E-5 s^-1}$ at a concentration of $\pu{8.71E-5 M}.$ Calculate the rate constant for the activation step in the mechanism.

From what I've understood the equation that I should be using is:

$$ \frac{1}{k_\mathrm{eff}} = \frac{k^{'}_\mathrm{a}}{k_\mathrm{a}k_\mathrm{b}} + \frac{1}{k_\mathrm{a} [\ce{A}]}\label{eqn:1}\tag{1}$$

However I don't quite understand how this equation is derived from this:

$$\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{P}]}{\mathrm dt} = k_\mathrm{eff}[\ce{A}],\tag{2}$$

where

$$k_\mathrm{eff} = \frac{k_\mathrm{a}k_\mathrm{b}[\ce{A}]}{k_\mathrm{b} + k^{'}_\mathrm{a}[\ce{A}]}\tag{3}$$

If we assume that  $k^{'}_\mathrm{a}[\ce{A}] \gg k_\mathrm{b},$ shouldn't $\displaystyle k_\mathrm{eff} = \frac{k_\mathrm{a}k_\mathrm{b}}{k^{'}_\mathrm{a}}?$

I have only seen a similar problem using the pressure and they get a new equation from \eqref{eqn:1}, which looks like:

$$\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^{'}} = \frac{1}{k_\mathrm{a}}\left(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{p^{'}}\right)\tag{4}$$

which they use to solve for $k_\mathrm{a}$ and that is the rate constant for the activation step. I don't quite understand how they get that equation either.

How is \eqref{eqn:1} derived and how can it be rewritten as the last equation to solve for $k_\mathrm{a}$?

Comment: Write down the equations for $\ce{A + M<=> A^*  + M;\; A^*\to products}$ and apply steady state to $A^*$.

Comment: @porphyrin Thank you! I think I understand how the equations are derived. I modified eq. (4) from pressure to concentration and got that $k_a = 0.191 M^{-1} s^{-1}$. Hopefully this is correct :)